# Can we send values to a form through a link?

Tags: html, jsp

I wanna send values to a Registration form via links. I want it to send different values depending on what link is used to access the page...

For example; 
If a link called Add User is clicked I want a value like "User" sent as a parameter
If a link called Add Admin is clicked I want a value like "Admin" sent as a parameter

I also want the Parameter to be not seen on the url....

Comment: `"I also want the Parameter to be not seen on the url"` - Then it can't be just a link.  A link is, in its entirety, a URL.  You can't have a basket that carries apples without putting apples in the basket.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a link that includes parameters without the parameters being visible.

If it's just a question of aesthetics, you can always have the link point to the form and then have the form save that value in some sort of internal storage (sessions? a database? a cookie? whatever's appropriate in your situation) and then redirect to a URL that doesn't include the parameter.

Your other option is to use JavaScript and AJAX to have the link submit a form "behind the scenes", and then reload the page yourself using the results of that AJAX request.

Comment: _italic_ **bold** `<script language="javascript"> 

   function Admin(){
      $.post("Register.jsp", { rrole: "Admin" } ); 
   }
</script>` This should work right? But how would I manually redirect it to Register.jsp ??

Comment: If you just need to redirect, wait for the call to complete and then just do `window.location.href = '...';`

Answer (score 0):

Use simple [**jQuery ajax**](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for pass the values. Add jquery library in header,

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
                                                            </script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "servletURL",
        data : {  field1: "admin", field2 : "user"}
        type : "POST",
        success: function (response) {
            //your success code
        },
        error: function () {
            //your error code
        }
    });
});
</script>
```